# Verify error in PHP - openssl_verify()

Tags: php, php-openssl

I am trying to verify signature via `openssl_verify()` function:

PHP code:

```
$signature = pack("H*", $ecdsa);
$verified = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key, "sha256");
```

Error message:

> error: error:0606C06E:digital envelope routines:EVP_VerifyFinal:wrong
>   public key type

What means error message "wrong public key type"?

**Parameters**

Data param:

> 41.50978123OK1140720161227221826993f133b2b22d61a6e5bcc5323c00438b489ffac9301b20811d696eb03d7

ECDSA param:

> 304502201dc866a213bdcf42fad84ab8d00dc3ef4d0e10450fd6110070a866dbdeccc831022100f8062057f3022db78f7df3bff40547ef76be58eb55cb9f72a4b1ecc9f34ed54b

Public key:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEozvFM1FJP4igUQ6kP8ofnY7ydIWksMDk1IKXyr/T
>   RDoX4sTMmmdiIrpmCZD4CLDtP0j2LfD7saSIc8kZUwfILg==
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Comment: are you using `openssl_pkey_get_public` to fetch the public key file?

Comment: No, I have a public key stored as a `string` in my app configuration.

Comment: @Artegon, I have the same problem. do you have a solution? it's look like bank security check ..